# C program, header file not found

Tags: c

I am using 2.6.18 CentOS. I am using headers, which on compiling is saying not found. 
Any idea, as how to resolve it?

```
timer_ex1.c:3:24: error: sys/netmgr.h: No such file or directory
timer_ex1.c:4:26: error: sys/neutrino.h: No such file or directory
timer_ex1.c:5:25: error: sys/siginfo.h: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, the files aren't found in the include path.

To get rid of that, locate `sys/netmgr.h` on your system. The parent path of `sys` must be in the include paths passed to the compiler when building `timer_ex1.c`

Comment: I could not find it in my system, i guess my CentOS version is not too old. Then why these syscall headers are missing? Any idea?

Comment: Looks like header files for QNX, not CentOS.

Comment: @Steve-o: Yes, that is the problem i guess :-(